# Why does strtok_r always find the pattern "."?

Tags: c, strtok

On my system, the following program:

```
int main(){
        char *strgptr;
        char buf[5] = {'b','a','a','a','\0'};
        char *tmp = strtok_r(buf, ".", &strgptr);
        if(tmp != NULL){
                printf("Found a . in baaa?\n");
                printf("It was found starting at: %s\n", tmp);
        }
        else
                printf("Everything is working.\n");
}
```

prints:

```
Found a . in baaa?
It was found starting at: baaa
```

However, if I swap the "." delimiter string in strtok_r for "a", I get (as expected):

```
Found a . in baaa?
It was found starting at: b
```

But swapping the "." for any other char not appearing in buf (e.g. "c") produces:

```
Found a . in baaa?
It was found starting at: baaa
```

The man page for strtok_r, as expected, says:

```
The strtok() and strtok_r() functions return a pointer to the next token, 
or NULL if there are no more tokens.
```

So why does strtok_r fail to return NULL when passed a string which contains none of the tokens in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the delimiter isn't found, so you're getting the whole string returned. It acts as if there's an invisible delimiter after the string.

Comment: @JohnDoucette Good question ... I guess it's not very obvious, although the opposite (your expected outcome) isn't obvious either, to me.

Comment: My thought was that, since I must have some way of accessing buf (to pass it along to the strtok call), returning a pointer to buf after calling strtok is pointless, since I can't tell whether or not the string contained my delimiter without doing a strcmp or similar. In contrast, if NULL is returned, I still have buf, but now it's an O(1) operating to check whether the delimiter was present. I guess I could operate on strgptr instead, but that's an implementation specific solution...

Comment: @John: it's documented in the standard: "The `strtok` function then searches from there for a byte that is contained in the current separator string. If no such byte is found, the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to by s1". The man page on my system doesn't say that -- personally I think it's defective, because it describes how "subsequent tokens" are returned but doesn't actually say what the "first token" is in the case where there are no delimiters.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks! Good to know that it's documented somewhere at least. Odd that it's not either of our man pages though.

Comment: @John: it's a common hobby of people who implement standards, to re-write the text of the standard in a way that they consider simpler. They probably win more than they lose in terms of creating a quick-reference guide to the standard, but are often less precise and so you should always go to the standard if you're surprised by the behavior or if the man page is vague. In this case the man page is vague but I don't think it's *obviously* vague, I can see how you read it the way you did.

Comment: There is a reason why I don't trust man pages with regards to C standard functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since the delimiter "." is **not** found in `buf`, your call to `strtok` successfully returns a pointer to your first (and only) token: `"baaa"`.

Comment: Okay, this makes some sense, but why is it designed this way? For instance, in the above code, I can't use if(tmp != buf), because it will always be equal to buf for the first token. So checking whether the delimiter is present at all needs to be a totally separate operation. Seems wasteful, since strtok ends up checking that anyway in the course of its work.

Comment: The reason that it's designed this way is that `strtok` is for splitting a string into tokens separated by the delimiter. Your string consists of one token (not none) in the same way that the string "hello" contains one word (not none).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you actually need to use the function strstr(). strtok_r is to split strings for example on commas or \n.